Assistance Needed to Identify PhD Advisor of Herbert Joseph Reich
I am currently working on creating an academic genealogy tree for physicists specializing in electric discharges. As part of this project, I am trying to identify the PhD advisor of Herbert Joseph Reich, who earned his PhD in physics from Cornell University in 1928.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Herbert_Reich_(engineer)
Despite extensive searching, I have been unable to determine his advisor. Although his PhD thesis is accessible online, it is only 18 pages long and does not mention the advisor. It appears to be a published paper rather than a traditional thesis. You can view the document here:
https://www.proquest.com/pqdtglobal/docview/301781922/citation/1CB9BCA90FB549C4PQ
The earliest publication by Reich dates back to 1926, co-authored with Professor Frederick Bedell from the same department: https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/17799016/
However, the paper does not provide any clear indication that Bedell was his advisor.
Is there another way to determine who his PhD advisor might have been? Any assistance or suggestions you could offer would be greatly appreciated.

Maybe try asking here: https://hsm.stackexchange.com/

I’m voting to close this question because it seems to be about physicists rather than physics.

In addition to my answer below, see the replies to the OP’s question at https://www.reddit.com/r/Cornell/comments/1ex8w6v/trying_to_find_the_advisor_of_a_cornell_physics/

Although this may be the wrong place to ask your question,
this may provide the answer to your question:

Frederick Bedell (Cornell)

according to https://academictree.org/etree/tree.php?pid=871990

I don't know who assembled this tree.

Another resource does not provide an advisor:
https://genealogy.math.ndsu.nodak.edu/id.php?id=188422
but does list a descendant
"Fett, Gilbert  University of Illinois at Urbana-Champaign  1940    8 descendants"

You could also check the online library catalog at Cornell.
Possibly useful, if it's Bedell:
Frederick Bedell papers, 1891-1984.
Collection Number: 14-22-2190
Division of Rare and Manuscript Collections
Cornell University Library
https://rmc.library.cornell.edu/EAD/htmldocs/RMA02190.html
which lists correspondence with Reich in Box 5, Folder 6.

Wow! Thank you so much! This is very helpful. I did not know about academictree webpage.

The math genealogy page now shows Bedell as advisor.   Presumably this was updated since you posted this (in the 13 hour window between your post and this conment), and quite probably as a result of this post.
